# Make Android Command Not Running. (Mobile Go-Ethereum)

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

Planning to make some modifications to the go-ethereum mobile code,so inorder to do that need to use "make android" command which will create the geth.arr (Manual builds: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile:-Introduction). But, "make android" not running properly, getting the following errors-

> build/env.sh go run build/ci.go aar --local
>   /usr/local/go/bin/go get golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile /home/snappybot/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/build/bin/gomobile init /home/snappybot/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/build/bin/gomobile: mkdir /home/snappybot/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/pkg/gomobile/work-782691719: permission denied util.go:43: exit status 1 exit status 1 Makefile:28: recipe for target 'android' failed make: *** [android] Error 1

Please Help.

Comment: Hi there. This is presumably a permissions issue while trying to create a directory: `permission denied...`. I'm assuming you're running the build as the `snappybot` user, so it's not clear why it can't make a directory under `/home/snappybot/`. You could attempt the build as the `root` user, using `sudo` (assuming you're on Linux).

Comment: Hi Richard, I am working on Linux and I have tried using "sudo make android" it doesn't work.Also, other commands like "make" and "make geth" are working but using "sudo make" or "sudo make geth", they won't work as well. Can you suggest something else that can resolve this problem?? ...Thanks for replying